# How do I create a static array containing my custom class?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a method that returns an array of custom class objects that are created by parsing  a text file. At the moment every time I use it I am rereading the file which isn't very efficient.

What I wat to do is create an array containing the objects when the page loads and store them in an array which can then be used later.

The method is:

```
public Album[] readArray(string sTextFilePath)
    {
        string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath(sTextFilePath));
        Album[] Albums = new Album[allLines.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < allLines.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] lineSplit = allLines[i].Split(',');
            Albums[i] = new Album();
            Albums[i].ID = Convert.ToInt32(lineSplit[0]);
            Albums[i].title = lineSplit[1];
            Albums[i].keyName = lineSplit[2];
        }

        return Albums;
    }
```

and the class is simple, just:

```
    public class Album
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string keyName { get; set; }
}
```

I thought I could create the static object using something like:

```
static Album myAlbums[] = readArray("Albums.txt");
```

but I am getting the following error:

**A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property 'B2M._Default.readArray(string)'**

I am new to C# so this is probably something dumb. (Feel free to poke fun in my general direction if this is the case!)

Thanks in advance for any assistance,

Ben

Comment: @Svish: Probably that `readArray()` doesn't exist in a static context

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"An error" isn't very descriptive. When you're posting a question and you're getting an error, please state what that error is.

In this case the problem is that you're trying to call an *instance* method (`readArray`) from a static context, without specifying an instance.

The method doesn't appear to require any instance data, so you should be able to just make the method static and all will be well.

I'd encourage you to read up on .NET naming conventions, btw. You might also want to think about using a `List<T>` instead of an array. When you feel more confident, you could also make this code simpler using LINQ - but I'd wait until you're more familiar with C# first.

Comment: @Jon, thanks for the pointer. At risk of showing my ignorance, to make the method static do I just change the method to public static Album[]?

Comment: @Jon - When I do this it seems to lose the Server namespace from Server.MapPath. Gives the following error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Page.Server.get'

Comment: @Ben: Yes, you just add the static modifier. I hadn't spotted the Server.MapPath usage - the problem is that's an instance property (i.e. it belongs to an instance of the type, not the type itself). The same type could be used in different places, with different mappings... I'm not sure of the best workaround for that.

Comment: @Jon - Cheers, I fixed it by changing it to: HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(sTextFilePath) - not entirely sure why!

Comment: @Ben: That will only work if the type is first initialized from within a web request. It's *probably* okay, but it's worth being aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Except for the static context, shouldn't it be:

```
static Album[] myAlbums = readArray("Albums.txt");
```